# How to configure mysql2 database in heroku

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, mysql2

I am using mysql database in my rails application, my development database is mysql2. I want to set mysql2 database in heroku. how to configure mysql2 database in heroku?

Answer (score 0):

Heroku uses Postgres by default, so it is recommended to set your production database to Postgres.

If you really want to stick to mysql your could either use the mysql2postgres gem to translate your mysql database to postgres or you can use addons:

https://addons.heroku.com/#data-stores

In your case you could use ClearDB MySql database. It does require more effort than using the default Postgres database though, but this guide might help:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cleardb

Comment: cant we use mysql as my production database?

Comment: Not if you are using Heroku, which uses Postgres by default. You could try to implement the mysql2psql gem, but I highly recommend to switch to Postgres.

Comment: Yes there are, I adjusted my answer. Postgres is not the only option, only the recommended/default.

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve your database URL by issuing the following command:

```
$ heroku config | grep CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL
CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL => mysql://adffdadf2341:adf4234@us-cdbr-east.cleardb.com/heroku_db?reconnect=true
```

then copy the value of the CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL config variable.

```
$ heroku config:set DATABASE_URL='mysql://adffdadf2341:adf4234@us-cdbr-east.cleardb.com/heroku_db?reconnect=true'
```

from here:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cleardb